# Securing Upholstery Pattern To Bench Seat

Tags: modeling

I made this pattern for a Model T seat and now I cannot figure out how to attach the edges that are sticking up to the bench seat underneath. I have tried using shrinkwrap modifier but it did not work. I appreciate any help you may provide.
[image]

Comment: maybe you'd better extrude it down to model the shape underneath? Or boolean? Or please share a picture of the original object so that we can suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Extrusion worked well in this case.